# how to back-port C++11 language constructs to MSVC 2012?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++-2012

I got a piece of third party library to my hands in form of some non-open SDK (sorry for not providing it's name; it is not "boost").
By running cmake on it i created a set of project and solution files for Visual Studio 2012 (v11 for x86_64). When trying to comile it, the builc choked first on those block (added minimal obfuscation):

```
  namespace sdk_name
  {
    namespace iterator
    {
        [...]
        template <typename T, typename T1, typename ... R>
        struct is_same_or_convertible
        {
            static const bool value =
                is_same<T, T1>::value ||
                std::is_convertible<T, T1>::value ||
                is_same_or_convertible<T, R...>::value;
        };
```

The first error appearing in the build outputs is this:

```
  2>C:\Program Files\sdk_name\include\sdk_name/Iterator.hpp(44): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'
```

The documentation tells about need for a C++11 compliant compiler that would mean at least Visual Studio 2013. Actually i have 2012 and just want to keep it for now as the tool of choice in the current project - this has various reasons.

Is there a chance to make such language objects compatible with MSVC 2012 by changing them to a functionally more or less equivalent variant? can you give me some hint what that statement is choking about, what it does mean and how the next best equivalent for my tooling could look like?

Comment: Btw. `C++11 compliant compiler that would mean at least Visual Studio 2013` No. No VS version is fully compliant.

Comment: VS2012 [does not have variadic templates at all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: you can check all the things where `std::` is written before and see whether it was available before c++11. In your case in the example look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible .... well yeah and variadic templates.

Comment: *Why* use VS 2012 when VS 2015 Community (=Pro) is free? Besides, *all* C++ compilers (not just older Visual C++ compilers) support different features of the current standard. The best level of support is obviously offered by the latest version of each compiler. You could even use VS Code [with the latest C++ compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)

Comment: reasons for 2012:
* the existing joint code base is proven to work with VC 2012
* the community edition might not be an option
* this question is done in order find out if costs/efforts can be lesser if just porting back a few lines of maybe not at all needed codes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: VS2015 very much is non-free. At best it's gratis to some people, but for small companies that just exceed the minimum it is actually quite expensive.

Comment: @MSalters Pro is $500 maximum. That's not "quite expensive". You can also work with VS Code and the CPP tools

Answer (score 1):

As the comments point out, VS2012 does not have variadic templates. That might be surprising, since you *do* have `std::tuple<...>`. But have a peak at its implementation: you'll see that its implementation is not actually variadic. They just defaulted every argument, and limited the total number of arguments.

This is already a bit of a hack for `std::tuple`, and it might be even more work for you. Plus, it involves rewriting that third-party code. But if you absolutely, positively have to get it working on MSVC2012 and don't mind the huge effort, then that's how you work around variadic templates.

Comment: Note that `boost` has (had) some macros that help with expanding a bunch of code for 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... type instances (with a fixed upper bound).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may do something like:

```
struct None{};

template <typename T, typename T1,
          typename T2 = None,
          typename T3 = None,
          typename T4 = None,
          typename T5 = None>
struct is_same_or_convertible
{
    static const bool value =
        is_same<T, T1>::value
        || std::is_convertible<T, T1>::value
        || is_same<T, T2>::value
        || std::is_convertible<T, T2>::value
        || is_same<T, T3>::value
        || std::is_convertible<T, T3>::value
        || is_same<T, T4>::value
        || std::is_convertible<T, T4>::value
        || is_same<T, T5>::value
        || std::is_convertible<T, T5>::value;
};
```